# Using regex to remove all newlines within <li> </li>

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, vb.net

I have a string like this

```
<li>something is\n here</li>
```

but it should be

```
<li>something is here</li>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: given that new lines in HTML aren't rendered by the browser, does it really matter?

Comment: im parsing the html so I unfortunately dont have that luxury =(

Comment: Ctrl + H, Replace with '\n' to " " :)

Comment: a decent HTML parser should also be able to deal with new lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a Regex replace:

`(?<=<li>.*?)\n(?=.*?</li>)`

I've used it like instead of `\n`, I've tested it with the letter `e`:

`<li>elelele</li>` results in `<li>lll</li>`

`eee<li>elele</li>e` results in `eee<li>ll</li>e`

Comment: To be honest... parsing HTML can be quite difficult with regex. I would convert the HTML to XHTML and query it with an XML document to do the clean-up.

Comment: Perfect! You truly are amazing at this (you answered my other regex question too). I'm doing most of the parsing with HTMLAgilityPack, but there are some things it can't do. Do you have any tutorials on regex? That program you recommended is amazing.

Comment: Btw, is there any way you could explain how this one works? It's baffling me.

Comment: Well... it is sometimes hard to explain. They are easy to make, but difficult to reproduce ;-). To answer still has some problems, especially with nested li's. Also it has problems with `<li>1\n2</li>\n\n<li>3</li>`... because it will remove the `\n\n` in the middle. You might want to consider this one: `(?=((?!<li>).)*</li>)\n`... but I'll explain later :P

Answer (score 0):

You could always read the HTML into a string and then do string manipulations on the `<li>something is\n here</li>` using the indexof() property to get the correct position and then remove the \n using the string.replace() functionality.  Unless you have to use Regex this would work just as well!

Answer (score 0):

```
string html1 = "<li>something is\n here</li>";
            html1 = html1.Replace("\n", "");
```